# Environment that generates table

Tags: tables, environments

I'm trying to define new nested environments that produce a 2x2 table. Each table cell in the second row will contain a source code.

**What I tried to do-**

Class file:

```
\newenvironment{example}
{
    \begin{table}[]
        \centering
        \caption{Caption of Table}
        \label{my-label}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Input & Output \\ \hline
    }
    {
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
}

\newenvironment{inputExample}
{}{&}

\newenvironment{outputExample}
{}{}
```

TeX file:

```
\begin{example}
    \begin{inputExample}
        Left
        column
        content...
    \end{inputExample}
    \begin{outputExample}
        Right column content...
    \end{outputExample}
\end{example}
```

I don't know why, but it is not working. I got many error messages like-

> 'Missing } inserted. ...gin{inputExample}Left column content... \end{inputExample}'

If I remove the `&` from the definition of the input example environment, it works. But it obviously doesn't produce the correct table.

**What I want is-**

[image: table]

Comment: Are these tables to show a LaTeX code on the left and its result on the right? If so, the [`showexpl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showexpl) package may be a better fit.

Comment: Actually, it must show two source codes (like, one in C++ and the other one in Java). Anyways, I'd like to know why the cited errors happen. The structure seems to be OK.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an initial proposal with `tcolorbox`. If you consider using it, some more work can be done to better adjust. This version uses `tcbitem` to include all four elements and all four boxes are similar, but all of them can be particularly designed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\caption{A nice table simulated with \texttt{tcolorbox}} 
\begin{tcboxeditemize}[raster columns=2, colback=white, sharp corners, raster equal height=rows, raster force size=false, raster column 1/.style={add to width=-3cm}, raster column 2/.style={add to width=3cm}]{notitle,colback=white, sharp corners, boxsep=-2pt}
\tcbitem Input
\tcbitem Output
\tcbitem Left column content
\tcbitem Right column content
\end{tcboxeditemize}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT:

It's possible to convert the `tcboxeditemize` in an simple `environment`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{mybox}{%
\begin{tcboxeditemize}[raster columns=2, colback=white, sharp corners, 
    raster equal height=rows, raster force size=false, 
    raster column 1/.style={add to width=-3cm}, 
    raster column 2/.style={add to width=3cm}]%
    {notitle,colback=white, sharp corners, boxsep=-2pt}}%
{\end{tcboxeditemize}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\caption{A nice table simulated with \texttt{tcolorbox}} 
\begin{mybox}
\tcbitem Input
\tcbitem Output
\tcbitem Left column content
\tcbitem Right column content
\end{mybox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd like to do that with new environments.

Comment: @LeandroLuque You can always declare a `newenvironment` to use `tcboxeditemize`. Please see my edit.

Comment: Can you explain why the original version did not work?

Comment: Exemple above doesn't compile with overleaf.com (error produced :LaTeX Error: Environment tcboxeditemize undefined.) Is there a way to fix easily?

Comment: @pzorba75 Because overleaf use an old tcolorbox version. I think you can download a recent package version in your project folder.

Comment: @Ignasi : it works fine on my PC with Miktex 2.9. I'm used to run SX exemples first on overleaf.com in order to understand questions and related answers, sometimes not understandable to me.